# UriFormatException does not exist in .NET for Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

Any idea how Uri.EscapeDataString() can throw a System.UriFormatException but it does not appear to be possible to catch it explicitly?

If I try to catch it explicitly I just get "type or namespace name 'UriFormatException' does not exist in the namespace 'System'"

Comment: Can you add the string which have problems?, potion of code? Did you add the namespace? .. try catch(System.UriFormatException ex) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Uri constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/z6c2z492.aspx) help in MSDN:

> In the .NET for Windows Store apps or the Portable Class Library,
>   catch the base class exception, FormatException, instead.

Comment: Thanks that's what I ended up doing. I just expected a better option. I'm surprised that's what they recommend.

Comment: I am speculating but I think the UriException did not offer anything new over the FormatException with this kind of app.